# Can a glass cup be used to collect positively-charged air ions from the Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, coulombs-law, air

I am wondering if the positively-charged air ions that are descending down from Earth's Ionosphere can be collected using a glass cup. Since a glass cup will allow an electric field to pass through it, and since there is an electric field between the Earth's Ionosphere and the ground, the positively-charged air ions descending down due to this electric field should be pulled into the glass cup and should start to accumulate within it.

The reason why I see the positively-charged ions accumulating within the cup is that as each positively-charged air ion enters the cup, a neutral air molecule within the cup will be pushed out of it to balance the air pressure within the cup.

The drawing below illustrates how I think the mixture of positively-charged air ions and neutral air molecules would look like within the glass cup after a period of time.

[image]

This glass cup could be placed on top of a wooden table and this table could be placed in the middle of an open field, and ideally, this experiment would be done on a fair-weather day in which there would be very little to no wind blowing. Wind will ruin the experiment since it will stir up all the air molecules within the cup, resulting in the collected positively-charged air ions to exit the cup and neutral air molecules to enter into it.

My goal is to collect positively-charged air ions within the cup and to then place a piece of glass over the top of it and to then secure it in place using a strong non-conductive adhesive. I will then observe how strongly both negatively-charged and neutrally-charged materials will be attracted to the cup. I also want to find out how long (in minutes/hours/days) this glass cup will keep attracting materials to itself due to it having positively-charged air ions trapped inside of it.

Can a glass cup be used to collect positively-charged air ions from the Earth's atmosphere?

Comment: If the air around us had a large proportion of positive ions and if they fell downwards like this, surely every cellar, cave and mineshaft would quickly fill up with positive ions and build up a large static charge ?

Comment: Have you thought about the fact that as soon as the charge from your positive ions balances the negative charges lining the cup, the cup will be neutral? (This will require less than a molecule-thick layer of positive charges.)

Comment: @gandalf61, as far as I understand atmospheric electricity, as soon as a positive ion descending down through the air comes in contact with the ground it instantly attracts an electron to itself and becomes a neutral air molecule. So, to answer your question, no, those places would not fill up with positive ions.

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy, yes, I have thought about that, but as far as I know, the Earth's electric field will still pass through a neutrally-charged glass cup and will continue to pull the positive ions that are descending down through the atmosphere down into the cup and these positive ions should accumulate within the cup.

Comment: I think you have several misconceptions. What is "the Earth's electric field?" There isn't some all-pervading negative potential that is attracting positive charges to the Earth. And if there were, what's the point of your cup? Wouldn't this magical rain of positive charges be covering everything?

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy, I'm referring to the positively-charged air ions that are descending down through the atmosphere from the Ionosphere. There is an electric field that exists between the positively-charged Ionosphere and the negatively-charged ground.

Comment: I see; you're referring to the overall negative surface potential of the Earth, relative to the atmosphere. Why do you imagine that the positive ions falling into your cup don't negate this field for the next "layer" of positive ions falling into your cup? And why do you suppose the Earth's negative charge isn't immediately canceled by a rain of adsorbed positive charges? Surely the role you're ascribing to the ground neutralizing positive charges would reduce the ground's negative charge.  Etc...

Comment: @RaghuParthasarathy, so you are saying that the electric field will be blocked/negated by layers of positively-charged air ions that would be accumulating within the glass cup? I don't know the answer to this because I am neither a physicist nor an electrical engineer, I am just someone who is asking about this out of scientific curiosity.

Comment: @user255577 No problem. Hopefully this helps: suppose you have a surface with some negative charges, and therefore a negative field above it. Then you layer on it an equal amount of positive charges. These generate an equal positive field. The electric field, therefore, above this surface will be *zero,* and so no further positive charges will be attracted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113771/discussion-between-user255577-and-raghu-parthasarathy).